# How can I add contrib modules to opencv3.1.0? (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015, aruco

I'm doing a simple AR-Project for school and have to use opencv for it. I found it quite tricky to install in visual studio but now it's working fine. Now I want to use the aruco module, I tried [this](http://audhootchavancv.blogspot.de/2015/08/how-to-install-opencv-30-and.html) tutorial, but after building the bin folder is missing and the includes in my code don't work anymore... Is there a (preferably easy) way of adding the contrib modules into my (saved and functioning) opencv-folder?

EDIT: I successfully build opencv with modules (using cmake gui and vs14) and the includes for my old code are working fine, but when I try to use the aruco module I get these: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh5Ns.jpg)

The files are all where they are supposed to be and I set all paths and additional dependencies as well as the include directory...

Any Idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I did it.
I disabled all other modules in cmake and now the includes for aruco work.
But I can't really explain myself why the other (unused) modules corrupt the aruco libraries?